# zsh alias command for la or ls, not working

Tags: shell, unix, terminal, zsh, zshrc

I've got a referenced file called `~/.zsh/aliases`. Inside this file, I have an alias:

```
alias la='exa --icons -lah'
```

In my `~/.zshrc`, I have sourced this file towards to bottom of the file:

```
source ~/.zsh/aliases
source ~/.zsh/path
source ~/.zsh/var
```

However, the `la` command is doing a "normal" `la`. I've tried with other aliases and they work. For example, `alias gc='exa --icons -lah'` will work. But if I assign `la` with something else, it also doesn't work. For example, `alias la='git commit'` doesn't work.

It seems like `la` is taken and can't be overwritten.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. General questions about Linux and its utilities should be posted to [unix.se] or [su] instead.

Answer (score 4):

For me the problem was the position of the alias inside the .zshrc file, i solved that by putting it to the bottom of the file. Hope it works for you too

Answer (score -1):

Fixed this issue by sourcing the referenced file from my terminal, rather than just inside `.zshrc`.

So, to work run this inside the terminal:

```
source ~/.zsh/aliases
```

Not sure why it wasn't getting picked up from `.zshrc`.

Comment: What does your `echo $ZSH_VERSION` say?

Comment: @user1934428 it says `5.8`

Comment: And you are sure that you were sourcing .zshrc after you had updated that file?

Comment: Yep, 100%. It's in my .zshrc at the bottom of the file.

Comment: I did not ask, where it **is**, I asked whether you **sourced** the file after changing it.

Comment: I guess not. That seems to have been my mistake :/